# ¿Cómo evitar la jerarquía de +layout.svelte en algunos directorios? Sveltekit

Tags: javascript, svelte

Necesito evitar la jerarquia de Layouts en Sveltekit. Vi en la documentación que podemos crear (grupos) que básicamente serian carpetas con nombres entre paréntesis o podrías hacer uso de +page@ para indicar el layout que queremos como tal, sin embargo, nada de eso me ha funcionado.

Por ejemplo tengo un proyecto que en la raíz tiene un +layout.svelte y tengo una ruta o directorio llamado por ejemplo panel y dentro de panel tengo otro +layout.svelte, por lo que el +page.svelte dentro de panel, quiero que tenga el +layout.svelte de panel y no el del directorio raíz. Porque hasta ahora solo se aplica la jerarquía y me muestran los 2 debido a que actualmente asi funciona Sveltekit.

Yo saque la información de aca, que son los layouts avanzados https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts pero aun asi no me funciono. Dejo un ejemplo de mi directorio y resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo en panel solo quiero ver el segundo layout

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es agrupar los directorios en base a los layout. que requieras:

```
src/routes/
│ (app)/ <- Grupo "app"
│  ├ iniciar/
│  ├ registro/
│  └ +layout.svelte <- Layout principal de los directorios dentro del grupo "app"
│ (panel)/ <- Grupo "panel"
│  ├ panel/
│  ├ perfil/
│  ├ +page.svelte
│  └ +layout.svelte <- Layout que afectará solo al grupo "panel"
```

Sveltekit router agrupa las carpetas que están entre paréntesis (name), por lo que para acceder a (panel) panel, simplemente pones localhost:XXXX/panel